# change auto-complete option inside its select method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, events, dom

Here's my code:

```
$authorizedRow = $('.authorizedRows').html()

$("#name").autocomplete({
        source: "userlookup.cfm",
        minLength: 3,
        select: function(e, ui) {
            $('#email').last().attr('value',ui.item.mail).attr('disabled','disabled');
            $('#phone').last().attr('value',ui.item.phone).attr('disabled','disabled');
            $('.authorizedRows').last().append('<button class="deleteRow">x</button>');
            $('.deleteRow').button();
            $('#people').append('<div class="authorizedRows">' + $authorizedRow + '</div>').autocomplete( "option", "appendTo", "#name");
        },
        change: function(e, ui) {
            if (a) {
                //not used yet
            }
        }
    });
```

So, what I'm trying to do is have this auto-complete on an input field, when a user selects it will autofill two other fields. These three fields (the name, phone, and email) are all contained in my authorizedRows div. It will append a button at the end of the 'last' authorizedRows div, then it will append a whole new authorizedRows div at the end of the 'people' div.

Where my problem is at is after the new row appends, the auto-complete will not work on the new name field in the new row. This is because the event-listener has not attached to the DOM element yet.

I tried to solve this by using the .autocomplete('option') on the people div selector, as you can see. It didn't work. Any ideas how I can get the auto-complete to work on my dynamically created field? Thanks.

Comment: Call .autocomplete() on the new input?

Comment: @Mark Like this? $('#name').last().autocomplete() This did not work.

Comment: You would still need to pass in the same options for autocomplete that you were previously. Not sure if $('#name').last() will return the correct element you expect.

Comment: @Mark This will lead to an infinite number of calls to autocomplete. The first dynamically added row will have this '2nd' autocomplete event listener, but when a user adds another row I run into the same problem because I still would have not attached an event listener to the newest (2nd) dynamically created DOM element.

Comment: Are you expecting an autocomplete for each new row that you add? If so, each needs its own autocomplete. You are creating a new instance of autocomplete for each input. This is not a bad thing but expected behavior. If you were to use a selector such as $('input').autocomplete(), it would return a new instance of autocomplete for each matching input.

Comment: @Mark This is what I tried to do with the .autocomplete('option','appendto') in the select option. On select it appends some html after the last #name input that has the autocomplete on it. That html has another #name input in it, so when I try to attach the autocomplete in the select option with the .autocomplete('option','appendto','#name') you see I use the #name selector, which has been created at this point but it is not attaching the event to.

Comment: appendTo will not attach an event to the element in your selector. appendTo just attaches the UI elements for an autocomplete. If you want the events, you still need to re-instantiate a new autocomplete instance on the new input field. From my understanding, you want users to be able to type and trigger an autocomplete on input fields that are injected dynamically, correct?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using a class selector instead of id.

**EDIT:**

jQuery selectors of IDs will return just the first one if there is more than one, that is why the event didn't attach to the other dynamically created fields. jQuery selectors of class will return an array for every class that matches the selector.

Comment: @aymeric I was the one with the problem in the first place. This explains the change I made that solved the question. jQuery selectors of IDs will return just the first one if there is more than one, that is why the event didn't attach to the other dynamically created fields. jQuery selectors of class will return an array for every class that matches the selector. That was my problem, this solved it.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Then to make it clear for the other users, you should consider to accept (the tick under the score) your own answer (I'll remove my comment right away).